# ImageView doesn't display Image from gallery

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to pick image from gallery, I added the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to `Manifest`, but it doesn't work fine. It take path `uri` of image but doesn't show it. Only rectangle with good proportions (screen and code below)

```
class NewRestaurantFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_new_restaurant) {

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "NewRestaurantFragment"
        private const val GET_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 2137
    }

    private lateinit var ivPhoto: ImageView

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        ivPhoto = view.findViewById(R.id.iv_photo)

        ivPhoto.setOnClickListener {
            selectPhoto()
        }
    }

    private fun selectPhoto() {
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.apply {
            type = "image/"
            action = Intent.ACTION_PICK
        }
        startActivityForResult(intent, GET_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE)
    }


    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == GET_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val uri = data!!.data

            ivPhoto.setImageURI(uri)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `, I added the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to Manifest, ` You do not need that permission.

Comment: Pick a much smaller image. One with a low resolution.

Comment: i think the problem is that you dont pass an uri with your intent